# How to generate an EXIF thumbnail for a JPEG?

Tags: jpeg, exif

I have a Canon Selphy printer and when trying to print images that have been edited on my computer a question mark appears in the viewer screen. It appears that the EXIF thumbnail in the image has been stripped out.

Is there an application to generate the EXIF thumbnail for an image?

I have tried using [JHead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) but that only regenerates the thumbail if there is already one present.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-g` option of [exiftran](http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftran):

```
exiftran -g -i image.jpg
```

The `-i` option does in-place modification to the file.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the generated thumbnail?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html):

```
nconvert -overwrite -buildexifthumb foo.jpg
```

Comment: I did this, but verexif.com still seems to give *There is no thumbnail*.

Answer (score 3):

The task can be completed with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) (for updating EXIF) and [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) (for crating thumbnails). 
First let's download and install/extract both programs. Put exiftool to any folder and include it to PATH  (Imagemagick folder was included to PATH during instalation). Next run cmd change to a folder with images and run

```
for /r %a in (*.jpg) do (Magick convert "%a" -resize 256x256 thmb.jpg &  exiftool(-k).exe "-ThumbnailImage<=thmb.jpg" "%a")
```

or with % doubled to be used in .bat

```
for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (Magick convert "%%a" -resize 256x256 thmb.jpg &  exiftool(-k).exe "-ThumbnailImage<=thmb.jpg" "%%a")
```

**Explanation**

convert creates 256px thumbnail thmb.jpg and exiftool writes it to original .jpg

**Note**

exiftool copies original file to .jpg_original which is supposed to be deleted after checking that the update was completed succesfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple tool called [Exif Thumbnail Creator](http://exifthumbnailcreator.suconsultorti.es). It's a software to create or reconstruct EXIF thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which OS you run.

If this is an option for you, you can try [Exif Thumbnail Adder](https://github.com/tenzap/exif-thumbnail-adder) which is an app for Android.

It is available on [Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exifthumbnailadder.app), [Amazon appstore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CZ7684J) (so it may work on windows 11), and [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.exifthumbnailadder.app/).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).